# how to split a string from a column using awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am a noob in Linux. I have a file like  this:

```
 col1                                  col2   col3
 ID1234567-DNA_A01 chr1_10203040_T/C   gene   0
 ID1234568-DNA_A02 chr1_10203050_T/A   gene   0
 ID1234569-DNA_A03 chr1_10203060_A/G   gene   0
 ID1234570-DNA_A04 chr1_10203070_C/T   gene   0
```

I want to use only the first column and divide each line into 4 columns:

```
 #CHROM  POS      REF  ALT
 1       10203040  T    C
 1       10203050  T    A
 1       10203060  A    G
 1       10203070  C    T
```

I tried to make:

```
  awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="\t"; print"#CHROM","POS","REF","ALT"} | cut -d' ' -f2- {print 
 substr($1,4,1),substr($1,6}' old_file > new_file
```

I know I did wrong, but any suggestion would be helpful!Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU awk (gawk), then - notwithstanding the advice [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) - you could consider capturing the parts you want using a regular expression rather than a string split:

```
$ gawk '
    BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "#CHROM","POS","REF","ALT"}
    match($2,/chr([0-9])_([0-9]+)_([ACGT])[/]([ACGT])/,a) {print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}
  ' old_file
#CHROM  POS     REF     ALT
1       10203040        T       C
1       10203050        T       A
1       10203060        A       G
1       10203070        C       T
```

(Other awk implementations have the `match` function, but the GNU version extends that with a capture group array.)

Comment: Great! Thnx.Just changed chr info (e.g. chr10, chrX), and writing here in case someone needs it:                     
  gawk '
    BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "#CHROM","POS","REF","ALT"}
    match($2,/chr([0-9XY]+)_([0-9]+)_([ACGT])[/]([ACGT])/,a) {print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}
  ' old_file > new_file

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $2}' file \
| awk -F'[_/]' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "#CHROM","POS","REF","ALT"}{$1=$1}1'
```

- First `awk`, output the second field only.
- Second `awk`, choose `[_/]` as field separator, print the new Header and the fields. `$1=$1` triggers reorganisation of fields, which is necessary as we change the output field separator to `\t`.
- You may add  `| column -t` to make the columns in line.

We could do it in one go, but then you need to use split which is more complicated I think.

---

Output:

```
#CHROM  POS       REF  ALT
chr1    10203040  T    C
chr1    10203050  T    A
chr1    10203060  A    G
chr1    10203070  C    T
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try like like this:

```
cut -d " " -f 2 test.txt | awk -F '[_,/]' 'BEGIN{printf "#CHROM \tPOS\tREF\tALT\n"} {printf ("%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n" ,$1, $2, $3, $4)}'
```

Here test.txt is name of your file. And if you want to redirect output to file just add `> new_file.txt` at end of the command.